# i need to insert an image in my listview

Tags: java, android

I am new in android development and I need to modify my code to make it show the text with image function:

print_view xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#BFAF80">


<ListView
    style="14dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/operations"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/operations"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/printer" />
```

---

list_row_item xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/wifi"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageForList" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Wifi"
        android:id="@+id/textForList" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/bluetooth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageForList2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Blutooth"
        android:id="@+id/textForList2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/usb"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageForList3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direct USB Connected"
        android:id="@+id/textForList3" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageForList4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Google Cloud Print"
        android:id="@+id/textForList4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

SettingsList java class:

```
public class SettingsList {

private int[] images;
private String[] items;

public SettingsList(int[] images, String[] items) {

    this.images = images;
    this.items = items;
}

public int[] getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(int[] images) {
    this.images = images;
}

public String[] getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(String[] items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

---

SettingsAdapter java class :

```
public class SettingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SettingsList> {


public SettingsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SettingsList> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderItems holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolderItems();
        holder.holderImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageForList);
        holder.holderImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageForList2);
        holder.holderImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageForList3);
        holder.holderImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageForList4);
        holder.holderText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textForList);
        holder.holderText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textForList2);
        holder.holderText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textForList3);
        holder.holderText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textForList4);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolderItems)convertView.getTag();
    }
    SettingsList current = getItem(position);
    holder.holderImage.setImageResource(current.getImages()[position]);
    holder.holderText.setText(current.getItems()[position]);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolderItems{
    ImageView holderImage;
    TextView holderText;
}
}
```

---

PrintView mainactivity :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class PrintView  extends ActionBarActivity {    private ListView lv;
private SettingsAdapter adapter;
private List<SettingsList> itemList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.print_view);
    int[] imgs = new int[]
            {
                    R.drawable.wifi,
                    R.drawable.bluetooth,
                    R.drawable.usb,
                    R.drawable.cloud,

            };
    String[] values = new String[]
            {"Nearby Wifi",
                    "Nearby Blutooth",
                    "Direct USB Connected",
                    "Google Cloud Print"

            };
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.operations);
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.add(new SettingsList(imgs, values));

    adapter = new SettingsAdapter(PrintView.this, R.layout.list_row_item, itemList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text

Comment: you are not even following my steps... You leave the adapter, list_row_item.xml, and SettingsList as they are....Remove the imageview from the print_view.xml

Comment: @KostasMatrix:
 
please help me :( by editing your answer,,, now you know exactly what i need .. i will appreciate that from you

Comment: check my answer....i editted. Copy and paste it as it is. and you will have your list working fine.

Comment: i did everything copy paste but the image didn't appear just the text !!

Comment: do you have the images in the drawable folder???did you named them correctly?

Comment: finally, it's work, thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) Create a res/layout/list_row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageForList" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/textForList" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) Create your custom List item:

```
public class SettingsList {

    private int image;
    private String item;

    public SettingsList(int image, String item) {

        this.image = image;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

3) Create your custom adapter

```
public class SettingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SettingsList> {


    public SettingsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SettingsList> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItems holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolderItems();
            holder.holderImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageForList);
            holder.holderText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textForList);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolderItems)convertView.getTag();
        }
            SettingsList current = getItem(position);
            holder.holderImage.setImageResource(current.getImage());
            holder.holderText.setText(current.getItem());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolderItems{
        ImageView holderImage;
        TextView holderText;
    }
}
```

4) In your Activity that you want the listview to be shown do this:

```
public class YourActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView lv;
    private SettingsAdapter adapter;
    private List<SettingsList> itemList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.operations);
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemList.add(new SettingsList(R.drawable.wifi, Nearby Wifi));
        itemList.add(new SettingsList(R.drawable.bluetooth, Nearby Blutooth));
        itemList.add(new SettingsList(R.drawable.usb, Direct USB Connected));
        itemList.add(new SettingsList(R.drawable.cloud, Google Cloud Print));
        adapter = new SettingsAdapter(YourActivity.this, R.layout.list_row_item, itemList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

5) The print_view.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BFAF80">


    <ListView
        style="14dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/operations"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: i have a problem with (images_array, string_array), cannot resolve it

Comment: what do you mean you cannot resolve it?check my editted answer

Comment: android make it with red line and said (cannot resolve symbol images_array)

Comment: i editted my answer...check it again. And also where i say images_array i mean that there you should put your int[] imgs, where i say string_array you should put your String[] values

Comment: i will edit my question with your steps and i need from you to see if i missed any of them or made mistakes